# Function in R saving in *.xls

Tags: r, function, xls

I created a program that breaks a database in several other banks. But in this program I save this several banks in txt so now I'd like save in xls, but I don't know how.

I tried `for (nm in Nms) write.table(Res[[nm]], paste(nm, 'xls', sep='.'), sep="\t",dec=",",col.names=TRUE, row.names=FALSE, quote=TRUE, na="NA")`

but it did not work

`decup <- function(dados,var){`

`require(gdata)`

`dados <- read.xls("dados.xls")`

`attach(dados)`

`Res = split(dados, var)`

`for (nm in Nms) write.table(Res[[nm]], file=paste(nm, 'txt', sep='.'))`

`for (nm in Nms) zip(paste(nm,'zip',sep='.'),paste(nm,'xls',sep='.'), zip = Sys.getenv("R_ZIPCMD", "zip"))`

`}`

Comment: Can you reformulate your question and say clearly what do you have as inputs and wht do you expect as outputs. It is not clear at all!! do you have many sheets ? Or do you want to have many data bases!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use library  `XLConnect` to read/write .xlsx files and 
`writeWorksheet` let's you save the your data.frames:

```
library(XLConnect)
## open workbook or create it if doesn't exist
wb <- loadWorkbook("writeWorksheet.xlsx", create = TRUE)
## for each data.frame create a sheet with its data
lapply(seq_along(Res), function(x)
   createSheet(wb, name = paste0("sheet",x))
   writeWorksheet(wb, Res[[x]], sheet = paste0("sheet",x), startRow = 4, startCol = 2)
 }

# Save workbook (this actually writes the file to disk)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

**EDIT** to save a data.frame by workbook you do this :

```
lapply(seq_along(Res), function(x){
  wb <- loadWorkbook(paste0("database",x), create = TRUE)
  createSheet(wb, name ='sheet1' )
  writeWorksheet(wb, Res[[x]], sheet = 'sheet1', startRow = 4, startCol = 2)
  saveWorkbook(wb)
})
```

Comment: rJava not running in ubuntu! :-(

Comment: :) `rJava` will work if you install it. Maybe you should java before. I claims also that rjava will works better under linux system. Maybe [this](http://r-interface.blogspot.fr/2012/04/install-r-jgr-and-deducer-in-ubuntu.html) can be helpful To install `rJava`.

Comment: agstudy thanks for your help, but I'd like creat separate databases and don't sheets separate. How I do this?

Comment: @user2514352 my solution is a single workbook with many sheets. But first of all, did you succeed to install rJava and test the above solution?

Comment: So , what ? Do you want to save all your data.frames in the same sheet?

Comment: I'd lije creat several data.frames broken for one variable. So I have for example 10001.xls, 10005.xls, 20001.xls.

Comment: I'd like creat several data.frames broken for one variable.So I have for example 1001.xls, 1005.xls, 2001.xls.

dput(dados)
structure(list(codigo = c(1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1005L, 
1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 
2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L, 2001L), sexo = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class = "factor"), idade = c(18, 
18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 22, 19, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 20, 18, 20, 18, 20, 22)), .Names = c("codigo", "sexo", "idade"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L
))